# Convex Hull = Boundary + Segments (follow up)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

My question is related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324037/convex-hull-boundarysegments?noredirect=1&lq=1), but even less general. Suppose $B \subseteq \partial A$ is a subset of the boundary of a compact convex set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the property mentioned in the question holds for the convex hull of $B$, $conv B$. i.e., suppose the boundary of $convB$ consists only of $B$ and segments that join two points from $B$. Can we, in that case, say that all points in $convB$ are convex combination of at most two points from $B$?

We can even assume $B$ is a connected subset of $\partial A$ if that makes this property hold.

For context, these are all ways I'm exploring to solve my original question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4215526/intersection-of-the-boundary-of-convex-set-with-probability-simplex).

As always, I'm most open to counterexamples which show this is false.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a tetrahedron (in $\Bbb R^3$) and $B$ its 1-skeleton, i.e., the "wireframe" made of $A$'s edges and vertices. This males $\operatorname{conv}(B)=A$ and as every point on a triangular face of $\partial A$ is on a line segment between two points on *its* boundary, $B$ has the required property (and is conneted).
However, *every* line segment between points in $B$ lies in such a triangular face, i.e., interior points of $A$ are not convex combinations of only two points of $B$.

Comment: This is super helpful. Thanks a lot.